# Is it known which links have Seifert fibered complements?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, seifert-fiber-spaces

I believe many such links can be constructed by looking at a foliation similar to the hopf fibration, but the wrapping leaves replaced with $(p,q)$ torus knots.  However, I'm interested in particular in whether there are classes of examples that don't fall under that construction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this paper exactly answers your question http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/1077378799 .

But you are basically right, the links you get are fibres (possibly degenerate) in some (possibly singular) Seifert fibration of $S^3$ and pretty much it can only be fibred in the ways you mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

The book of David Eisenbud and Walter Neumann on *Three-dimensional link theory and invariants of plane curve singularities* (Annals of Mathematics Studies, vol. 110,  Princeton University Press, Princeton, NJ, 1985) contains a discussion of Seifert links (Chapter II, Section 7). In particular, yes, there are many more Seifert links than $(p,q)$ torus knots or links, for instance, the "key-chain" links.  For more details, see also the paper of Ryan Budney, *JSJ-decompositions of knot and link complements in $S^3$*,  Enseign. Math. **52** (2006), no. 3-4, 319–359.